# non numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, vector, lapply

I want to get the different approx.n values depending on the value of n.grid
The code is the following:

```
ll <- 0
ul <- 0.5
mean <- 0
sdsq <- 1
n.value <- 100
n.value <- c(1:n.value)
xi <- lapply(n.value, function(i) seq(ll,ul,length.out = i+1))
xi <- xi[-1]
h <- (ul-ll)/n.value
fx <- sapply(xi, dnorm, mean= mean,sd=sqrt(sdsq))
indv.exact <- pnorm(ul, mean= mean,sd=sqrt(sdsq)) - pnorm(ll, mean= mean,sd=sqrt(sdsq))
approx.n <- ( h/3 ) * ( fx [1] + fx[n.value] )  +  ( 4*h/3 ) * sum(fx[seq(2,n.value-2,2)])  + ( 2*h/3 ) * sum(fx[seq(3,n.value -1,2)])
```

Sourcing the file gives the error

```
Error in fx[1] + fx[n.grid] : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Also for the following after this

```
( 4*h/3 ) * sum(fx[seq(2,n.value-2,2)])  + ( 2*h/3 ) * sum(fx[seq(3,n.value -1,2)])
```

I want 4*h/3 for the even values in n.value and 2*h/3 for the odd values adjusted for each value of n

Sorry for overcomplicating. thanks

Comment: With `xi <- xi[-1]` you change the `xi` list to be only 99 elements long (and as a result, the `fx` list is 99 elements long as well). The value of `n.grid` is 100, so with `fx[n.grid]` you're calling for the 100th element of the `fx` list, which is null (because there are only 99 elements).

Comment: fx[1] is a list containing a single vector of length 3, whereas fx[n.grid] is a length 100 list of variable lengthed vectors. It's not clear to me how you would intend these to be added, and R doesn't know either.

Comment: Also there's the problem that `fx` is a list of vectors with differing lengths (e.g. `length(fx[[1]])` is 3 and `length(fx[[99]])` is 101). You can only add vectors of equal lengths, so I think that's where you're getting your error.

Comment: Makes sense @Adam, but i want `fx[1]` to be one number where 1 is the first number in the sequence of `xi` and so on, where `fx <- dnorm( xi, mean = mean, sd = sqrt(sdsq) )` and `fx[n.value]` to also be on number. So i want `approx.n` to be a vector with `n.value` values for each value of `n.value`. So lets say `n.value` is set to 100. I want the final output of `approx.n` to be a vector of length n.grid where it has the value of `approx.n` for each increase in `n.value` from 1 to 100 and for the value of `h` to also change with each different value in `n.value`.

Comment: I still don't really understand your goal but if you want the first and the last values of each vector within `fx` you will probably need to use iteration.